# Facebook + Android Key Hashes

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to get work Facebook login in my Android app and i stack on key hashes: I made them using

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

then I upladed it to facebook. Now if I press login button, Facebook showing for 1 sec and shuting down, Nothing is showing in Logcat what is problem?

Marlen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your app develop version (not signed) just use this code to obtain hash:

```
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.your.package", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    }
```

To log this in your signed app use android:debuggable="true" in manifest

```
<application
    android:debuggable="true"
    ... 
</application>
```

Comment: Last step may not be necessary.  I got `Avoid hardcoding the debug mode; leaving it out allows debug and release builds to automatically assign one.` when I added that to manifest.  Without that, I still able to get the Hash.  Also suggest to remove this (and maybe the try code) after obtaining the Hash.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if your activity is being finished before calling the facebook dialog. If this is happening, then facebook dialog won't be able to call the launcher activity again.

Comment: I unistaled facebook app and webbrowser-based login works. But how to get work fb app to work?